# Best way to unwrap half a sphere or a helmet?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

Any chance anyone knows how to unwrap half a sphere? Or what the best way to unwrap half a sphere? I've been looking through forums and I couldn't find a way to unwrap my helmet.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Final:

[image: Final]

### Overview:

In this particular case I would go with **Follow Active Quad** unwrapping. You can 'cut off' the top of the helmet (there is another mesh there) so it's the easiest way I can think of.

### Steps:

[image]

First of all **Mark Seams** around the top of the helmet and one through the back of the mesh.

1. Select all faces and **Unwrap** them.
2. Select one face, preferably near the Seam, it will keep texture more seamless.
3. Align this face in **UV Image Editor** by selecting edges and <kbd>W</kbd> > **Align Auto**.
4. Select all faces on your mesh (keep aligned face as active face).
5. **Unwrap** it by **Follow Active Quads**.
6. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to Pack UV Islands.
7. Manually correct the top of helmet UV map.