# how can i transform a sphere into a plane

Tags: modeling, mesh, transforms

I want to make height maps and color maps to make planets in a game called ksp
and I already know how to he maps with a plane but I need polar distortion so I thought I could model it on a  sphere but I have no idea how to transform it properly

Comment: maybe related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3315/how-to-get-perfect-uv-sphere-mercator-projection and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24043/how-to-animate-morphing-a-rectangular-plane-into-a-sphere/24053#24053 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81172/best-way-to-unwrap-half-a-sphere-or-a-helmet and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10741/what-is-the-best-way-to-unwrap-a-sphere

Comment: Sorry they didn't have the right answers i was looking for r didn't work :/

Comment: If this answer is not suites for you, I don't know, that you need. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/89745/32374

Comment: No, what I want to do is model on a sphere then transform it into a plane for height mapping

Comment: nevermind I tried the first thing again and it worked thank you

Comment: wait hold on I having one big problem with this https://i.gyazo.com/3756c5eb0b03dda8956c465eb368b5ee.png
it wraps with the poles on the sides but i need them top to botem to generate proper hlight maps for this